# Coding in Python, print command does not act as expected

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : 500, 
    'sack' : ['rock', 'copper wire'],
    'weapons rack' : ['pistol', 'MP-5', 'grenade'],
    'ammo pouch' : ['Pistol ammo', 'MP-5 ammo'],
}

print "You have " + inventory['gold'][0] + " coins!"
```

I get the error message:

```
  line 8, in <module>
    print "You have " + inventory['gold'] + " coins!"
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

why wouldn't the console print out `"You have 500 gold coins!"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gold` entry is *not a list*; you are trying to index the `500` integer. Remove the `[0]`:

```
print "You have", inventory['gold'], "coins!"
```

Note that I used commas, not `+`, because you cannot just concatenate strings and integers like that. The alternative would be to convert the integer to a string first:

```
print "You have " + str(inventory['gold']) + " coins!"
```

You could also put the gold value into a list:

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : [500], 
    'sack' : ['rock', 'copper wire'],
    'weapons rack' : ['pistol', 'MP-5', 'grenade'],
    'ammo pouch' : ['Pistol ammo', 'MP-5 ammo'],
}
```

Note the `[...]` square brackets around the `500` value there. Then your `[0]` applies again:

```
print "You have", inventory['gold'][0], "coins!"
```